# Why My Filter On Javascript Only Showing First Row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello Everyone I Want To Ask Why My Filter On Javascript Only Showing First Row and can't be unfiltered? i'm newbie on javascript, i'm already give the class a number for checking but seems not working here's my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="height=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

    </style>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://livejs.com/live.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="test2.js"></script> -->
    <script>
    function change() {
        let results = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.result > div')),
            modelsChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.filter input.models:checked'),
            processorsChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.filter input.processors:checked');
        // Hide all results
        results.forEach(function(result) {
            result.style.display = 'none';
        });
        // Filter results to only those that meet ALL requirements:        

        filterModelsOrProcessors(modelsChecked);

        if (processorsChecked.length != 0) {
            filterModelsOrProcessors(processorsChecked);
        }

        function filterModelsOrProcessors(modelsOrProcessorsChecked) {
            results = Array.from(modelsOrProcessorsChecked).reduce(function(sum, input) {
                const attrib = input.getAttribute('rel');
                return sum.concat(results.filter(function(result) {
                    return result.classList.contains(attrib);
                }));
            }, []);
        }
        // Show those filtered results:
        results.forEach(function(result) {
            result.style.display = 'block';
        });
    }
    change();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="filter">
        <h1>Select models</h1>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" rel="apple" class="models" onchange="change()" />Apple</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" rel="samsung" class="models" onchange="change()" />Samsung</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" rel="xiaomi" class="models" onchange="change()" />Xiaomi</label>
        </div>
        <h1>Select processors</h1>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" rel="a9" class="processors" onchange="change()" />A9</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" rel="a8" class="processors" onchange="change()" />A8</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" rel="snapdragon" class="processors" onchange="change()" />Snapdragon</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" rel="exynos" class="processors" onchange="change()" />Exynos</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
        <div class="apple a9">
            <h1>iPhone 7</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="apple a8">
            <h1>iPhone 6</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="samsung exynos">
            <h1>Samsung s7</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="xiaomi snapdragon">
            <h1>Xiaomi Redmi note 4x</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what are you expecting as output here?

Answer (score 0):

You're hiding everything regardless of weather a filter is checked or not.
If no filter is checked when a change happens it means previous filters were removed, so you've to display all results

```js
function change() {
  let results = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.result > div')),
    modelsChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.filter input.models:checked'),
    processorsChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.filter input.processors:checked');
    
  // Start fresh, if nothing is checked this will display everything
  results.forEach(result => result.style.display = 'block');

  // Hide stuff that matches (only when there are filters)
  if (modelsChecked.length || processorsChecked.length) {
    // Hide all results
    results.forEach(result=> result.style.display = 'none');
    // Filter results to only those that meet ALL requirements:        
    filterModelsOrProcessors([...processorsChecked, ...modelsChecked]);

    function filterModelsOrProcessors(modelsOrProcessorsChecked) {
      results = results.filter(result => {
        return modelsOrProcessorsChecked.some(input => {
          const attrib = input.getAttribute('rel');
          return result.classList.contains(attrib);
        })
      });
    }
    // Show those filtered results:
    results.forEach(result => result.style.display = 'block');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
  <h1>Select models</h1>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" rel="apple" class="models" onchange="change()" />Apple
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" rel="samsung" class="models" onchange="change()" />Samsung
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" rel="xiaomi" class="models" onchange="change()" />Xiaomi
    </label>
  </div>
  <h1>Select processors</h1>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" rel="a9" class="processors" onchange="change()" />A9
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" rel="a8" class="processors" onchange="change()" />A8
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" rel="snapdragon" class="processors" onchange="change()" />Snapdragon</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" rel="exynos" class="processors" onchange="change()" />Exynos</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="result">
  <div class="apple a9">
    <h1>iPhone 7</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="apple a8">
    <h1>iPhone 6</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="samsung exynos">
    <h1>Samsung s7</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="xiaomi snapdragon">
    <h1>Xiaomi Redmi note 4x</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using classes on the display items I suggest using data- attributes like:

```
<div data-model="samsung" data-processor="exynos">
```

Then you can have a filter object that uses models as keys with a Set or array for each.

Those keys can then be used to both iterate the checkboxes to assign values to correct filter as well as when doing  lookups when iterating all the items up .

Then you only need to iterate the results elements once

If filters are empty, it's an automatic show, otherwise check the associated dataset properties for each item.

I'm not sure why you are using rel attribute and added `value` to each checkbox to match

```js
function change() {

  const filters = {
    model: new Set(),
    processor: new Set()
  };

  const types = Object.keys(filters)

  types.forEach(type => {
    const checked = document.querySelectorAll(`.filter .checkbox .${type}s:checked`)
    checked.forEach(el => filters[type].add(el.value));// using value rather than attribute
  })

  const showAll = types.reduce((a, c) => (filters[c].size ? false : a), true)

  const results = document.querySelectorAll('.result > div');

  results.forEach(el => {
    let show = showAll;
    if (!show) {
      show = types.every(type => {
        const set = filters[type];
        return !set.size || set.has(el.dataset[type])
      });
    }
    el.style.display = show ? 'block' : 'none'
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
  <h1>Select models</h1>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="apple" rel="apple" class="models" onchange="change()" />Apple
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="samsung" rel="samsung" class="models" onchange="change()" />Samsung
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="xiaomi" rel="xiaomi" class="models" onchange="change()" />Xiaomi
    </label>
  </div>
  <h1>Select processors</h1>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="a9" rel="a9" class="processors" onchange="change()" />A9
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="a8" rel="a8" class="processors" onchange="change()" />A8
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="snapdragon" rel="snapdragon" class="processors" onchange="change()" />Snapdragon</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="exynos" rel="exynos" class="processors" onchange="change()" />Exynos</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="result">
  <div data-model="apple" data-processor="a9">
    <h1>iPhone 7</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-model="apple" data-processor="a8">
    <h1>iPhone 6</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-model="samsung" data-processor="exynos">
    <h1>Samsung s7</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-model="xiaomi" data-processor="snapdragon">
    <h1>Xiaomi Redmi note 4x</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i use this the container i'm filtering is goes down

Comment: What does that mean?